# How to display orientation of a known CAD model on a 2d image?

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, cad

I have a CAD model (.stl) and different images of this model. I'm trying to plot the orientation of the model on the image using python.

I know the distance from the camera and also the true size of the model, and using OpenCV i was able to detect the contours of the model in the image.
As I am relatively new to python I would highly appreciate any guidance regarding how to match the CAD model to the image orientation.

Comment: By plot the orientation, do you mean display the XYZ axis as an overlay?

Comment: Exactly. And to calculate the change in orientation in degrees compared to the baseline orientation of the CAD model in each direction. Thanks.